# PWA has persistent Chrome notification

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-notifications, progressive-web-apps

Currently I'm trying to learn how to create a progressive web application and managed to create one by following an online tutorial. It's all good and well, not.

When I install this PWA with Chrome, it correctly installs and shows up in the Android's app library (Settings->Apps), but whenever is application is up and running as main process, there is a persistent Chrome notification that looks like in the image below. However if I install it with Samsung Browser, the exact opposite behavior is happening, that is there is no app icon in the Android's app library, but it doesn't have that persistent notification like Chrome has.

My desired behavior is to keep the app in the app library but remove that persistent notification when installed from Chrome browser. Current implementation of Samsung Browser is OK, as long as notification is invisible/hidden.

[Persistent Chrome Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oug3O.jpg)